# On an example for consistent initial values in differential-algebraic equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-algebraic-equations

I am studying differential-algebraic equations, that is, loosely speaking, equations of the form 
$$E\mathbf x'(t)=Ax(t)+f(t)$$
where $E,A\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$, $t\in[0,\infty)$ and $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb C^n$, subject to some initial condition $\mathbf x(t_0)=\mathbf c$. Here, the system can be expressed as a system involving an ODE and an algebraic equation, as in the following example.

Let $\mathbf x(t)=(x_1(t),x_2(t))$ for $t\in[0,\infty)$, and let $\mathbf c=(c_1,c_2)\in\mathbb C^2$. Consider the following differential-algebraic system (or equation),

\begin{align*}
x_1'(t)+x_2'(t)+x_1(t) & = 0\quad \text{when $t\in(0,\infty)$} \\
x_2(t)&= 0\quad \text{when $t\in(0,\infty)$}\\
\mathbf x(0)&= \mathbf c,
\end{align*}
where the last equation corresponds to the initial condition. The unique solution here is given by $\mathbf x(t)=(c_1e^{-t},0)$ for $t\in[0,\infty)$.

In differential-algebraic equations, the notion of a *consistent* initial value is central, and is used to describe when the corresponding initial value problem has at least one solution. I have read that for differential-algebraic equations, a key difference to ODEs is that, for a given initial condition, the system might not be solvable.

I'm trying to see how this is showcased in the above example - is it simply that for *any* initial value $\mathbf c=(c_1,c_2)\in\mathbb C^2$ where $c_2\neq0$, the corresponding initial value problem is not solvable?

Furthermore, what is the connection between this and the fact that for differential-algebraic equations, the matrix $E$ is allowed to have nontrivial kernel? How is it that $E$ having a nontrivial kernel enables the above?

Comment: Since the problem is solvable for all $\mathbf c$ with $c_2 = 0$, and is always solvable for $x_1$ (since $x_2' \equiv 0$), you have it exactly right: This is unsolvable exactly when $c_2 \ne 0$, because then $x_2$ is not continuous. If $E$ has trivial kernal, then multiplying through by $E^{-1}$ converts it to a known-solvable ODE. Therefore it can only be unsolvable when $E$ has non-trivial kernal.

Comment: On the latter point, just to be clear, if $E$ has non-trivial kernel, then $E$ is not injective and hence not invertible. And so, one cannot proceed by applying $E^{-1}$ and recovering a solvable ODE? Is this the main point there?

Comment: I would say the point is that if $E$ is invertible, then the equation reduces to a simpler equation that is solvable. Since this is the case, there is no particular reason to express the equation as differential-algebraic when $E$ is invertible. Therefore what one is interested in for differential-algebraic equations is the case when $E$ is not invertible. That is where problems not covered by the earlier theory are found. And as this simple example shows, in those new problems one is not always guaranteed a solution.

Comment: Paul, this has helped immensely - if you would be willing to post these points as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: I had started it as an answer, but thought it lacked too many details to qualify (and which I didn't want to pursue), so I converted to a comment. But if it satisfies your need, I'll put it in answer a little later so the question can be closed  (I've got something to do),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example, note that since $x_2 \equiv 0, x_2'\equiv 0$ also, so the first equation becomes $x_1' + x_1 = 0$, which has the unique continuous solution $x_1 = c_1e^{-t}$ for any $c_1$. $x_2$ also must be a specific function:
$$x_2(t) = \begin{cases}c_2,&t = 0\\0,&t > 0\end{cases}$$
The issue here is that we demand the solution be continuous at the boundaries - in this case, at $t = 0$. So this problem is only solvable when $c_2 = 0$, exactly because that is the only time $x_2$ can be continuous at $0$.

For the general problem, if $E$ has a trivial kernal, then it is invertible, so the equation can be rewritten as $$\mathbf x' = B\mathbf x + g$$
Where $B = E^{-1}A, g = E^{-1}f$. Thus when $E$ has trivial kernal, the problem can be recast as an ordinary multidimensional differential equation, which under sufficient regularity conditions will have local solutions. This case offers nothing new that requires a broader theory.

But when $E$ has a non-trivial kernal, $E$ will not have an inverse, so the previous results no longer guarantee a solution, no matter how regular $f$ is forced to be. This is demonstrated by the example, where $f \equiv 0$, which is as regular as any map can be.

The theory of differential-algebraic equation has been developed exactly to investigate the case when $E$ has non-trivial kernal, because the other case had already been covered.