# The relation between $\ker(E)$ and the differential-algebraic equation $E\mathbf x'(t)=Ax(t)+f(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-algebraic-equations

A differential-algebraic equation is, loosely speaking, an equation of the form 
$$E\mathbf x'(t)=Ax(t)+f(t)$$
where $E,A\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$, $t\in[0,\infty)$ and $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb C^n$, perhaps subject to some initial condition $\mathbf x(t_0)=\mathbf c\in\mathbb C^n$.

Based on the response here [On an example for consistent initial values in differential-algebraic equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633668/on-an-example-for-consistent-initial-values-in-differential-algebraic-equations), I see that if the matrix $E$ were invertible, then one could recover a 'usual' linear system of first order differential equations, and could try to apply methods from there to derive a solution.

On the other hand, if $E$ is not invertible, **in particular when the kernel of $E$ is non-trivial**, then one needs to use both the differential and algebraic part to determine which initial values are admissable and even determine the solution.

As the examples below highlight, a differential-algebraic equation can be viewed as a system involving a differential equation and an algebraic equation.

**Example 1:**

\begin{align*}
x_1'(t)+x_2'(t)+x_1(t) & = 0\quad \text{when $t\in(0,\infty)$} \\
x_2(t)&= 0\quad \text{when $t\in(0,\infty)$}\\
\mathbf x(0)&= \mathbf c,
\end{align*}
where the last equation corresponds to the initial condition.

**Example 2:**
\begin{align*}
x_2'(t) & = x_1(t)\\
0&= x_2(t)-t^3\quad \\
0&= x_3(t)-t,
\end{align*}
for $t\in[0,\infty)$, which is independent of an initial condition.

One thing I have read, which I don't completely understand, says that a differential-algebraic equation $E\mathbf x'(t)=Ax(t)+f(t)$ **involves a differential equation on $\ker(E)^\perp$** and **an algebraic equation on $\ker(E)$.**

**My questions are on this point.** How does one see that we should work with the differential part on $\ker(E)^\perp$ and the algebraic part on $\ker(E)$? How does this 'distinction' arise? Namely, how does the fact that we should make a distinction between *where* we consider the differential and algebraic part in their relation to $\ker(E)$ arise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two things. First, you are aware that because of finite dimension of $\mathbb{C}^n$,

$$ \mathbb{C}^n = \ker(E)\oplus \ker(E)^{\perp}$$

Secondly, given a function $y$, if

\begin{align} 
y' &\in \ker(E) \\ 
\implies 0 &= Ay + f \tag 1 
\end{align}

which gives an **algebraic equation** on $\ker(E)$. Next, given a function $z$ (for clarity), if

\begin{align}
z' &\in \ker(E)^{\perp} \\
\implies Ez' &= Az + f \tag 2
\end{align}

which is a **differential equation** on $\ker(E)^{\perp}$. This now gives a solution

$$x = y \in \ker(E) + z \in \ker(E)^{\perp}$$

You've a part given by $(1)$ and $\ker(E)$ and a part given by $(2)$ and $\ker(E)^{\perp}$.